# How to sync data between mysql and sqlite?

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, android-asynctask

I am developing an android application, It has a server side too. In server side i am using mysql and php. I want to sync the data between mysql and sqlite.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method #1 : Using Sync Adapter**

You can sync the device and a server using a Sync Adapter in android. See the developer documents.

[Creating a Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

Basically this requires you to extend your class with `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter` where you write your sync logic, create some xml files and a Content Provider to share your data.

With this method you dont have to handle network availability. All the work is basically done by android.

[This](https://github.com/neerajlal/Android-SyncAdapter-example) is an android sample I wrote using `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter` to sync data between device and a server. [This](https://github.com/neerajlal/Android-SyncAdapter-Sever-example) is its server side written in Java using `Servlet`. Please have a look.

**Method #2 : Using a simple API**

If you don't need all that complexity, you can just create an API that both accepts the data from the device and outputs the data on the MySQL database. You will need to write some logic to sync the data.

Good luck :)

Comment: I am using php in webside. Is there any examples for that ? where you are specifying the db ?

Comment: No I'm afraid I don't have anything related to PHP. I have used JDBC with derby database in the server side. I'm sure you can adapt the logic for PHP/MySQL.